# Any tutorials about how to create an ASP.NET MVC 2 website and run it against Local IIS Web Server (not use Cassini)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, debugging, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, cassini

does anyone have any good links/tutorials about how to create a simple ASP.NET MVC website, and have it run against a Local IIS7 Web Server, instead of the default Visual Studio Development Server (aka Cassini).

Yes, i tried google, but i fail at getting some good keywords, etc.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are my steps:
In IIS, Sites -> Add Web Site...

1. Fill in the name, whatever you want.
2. Set the physical path where your app is located.
3. In the Host Name option, type for example local.test.com
4. Hit OK

Then I update the hosts file located in $windir$\System32\drivers\etc
Adding the line

127.0.0.1 local.test.com

Don´t forget changing in the application pool of the created website the framework version.

I´m sure there must be other ways, I just follow this steps every time I want to create a new site in my local IIS and it works.

Good luck!

Comment: No need to update the hosts file. Instead go to http://localhost/yournameofthesite/