# ASP.NET MVC 2 View with PartialView - PartialView Opens New Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, partial-views, renderpartial

My code works perfectly in VS2010 C# but once published to IIS7 the PartialView (list of records) does not get rendered in the View...it rolls to a new page without the data except for the correct record count retrieved from SQL server. SQL server is on separate box.

I have searched for hours on this site with no luck finding a resolution.

**View with the RenderPartial:**

```
   <table style="width:100%">
<tr>
<td>
<h3>Outage Tracking List (Open or Active)</h3>
</td>
<td style="text-align:right">
<h1><%: ViewData["ApplicationName"]%></h1>
</td>
</tr>
</table>    

<% Html.RenderPartial("OutageSearch",this.ViewData.Model); %>
```

**PartialView:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<OutageTrackingWebSite.Models.OutageViewModel" %>
```

```
<div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

```
    function OutageSearch() {

        $("#OutageSearchForm #CurrentPageNumber").val("1");       
        PostSearchForm();

    }
```

**Various functions then the rest of the partialview**

```
  <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("OutageSearch", null,
        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "DivOutageSearchResults", OnComplete="OutageSearchComplete" },
            new { id = "OutageSearchForm" })) { %>

<table style="background-color: #ebeff2;  width: 100%; border:solid 1px #9fb8e9" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 60%; text-align: left">
            <input id="btnSearch" onclick="OutageSearch();" type="submit" value="List Open/Active" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="DivOutageSearchResults">    
 <% Html.RenderPartial("OutageSearchResults", this.ViewData.Model); %> 
</div>

<% } %>
```

**additional PartialView**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<%OutageTrackingWebSite.Models.OutageViewModel" >
```

```
    <input name="CurrentPageNumber" type="hidden" id="CurrentPageNumber" value="<%=Model.CurrentPageNumber%>" />
<input name="TotalPages" type="hidden" id="TotalPages" value="<%=Model.TotalPages%>" />     
<input name="SortBy" type="hidden" id="SortBy" value="<%=Model.SortBy%>" />     
<input name="SortAscendingDescending" type="hidden" id="SortAscendingDescending" value="<%=Model.SortAscendingDescending%>" />     

<input name="PageSize" type="hidden" id="PageSize" value="9" />

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
```

```
function GetOutageDetails(OutageID) {

             if (formIsDisabled == false) {

                 DisableForm();

                 formData = "OutageID=" + OutageID;

                 setTimeout(PostOutageIDToServer, 1000);

             }

         }

         function PostOutageIDToServer() {

             $.post("/Outage/GetOutageInformation", formData, function (data, textStatus) {
                 OutageUpdateComplete(data);
             }, "json");

         }
```

**Controller**

```
       public ActionResult DisplayOutageList()
        {


            Models.OutageViewModel outageViewModel = new Models.OutageViewModel();

            outageViewModel.TotalPages = 0;
            outageViewModel.TotalRows = 0;
            outageViewModel.CurrentPageNumber = 0;

            ViewData.Model = outageViewModel;

            string applicationName = Convert.ToString( System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationName"]);

            ViewData["ApplicationName"] = applicationName;

            return View("OutageMaintenance");
        }

        /// 
        /// Outage Search
        /// 
        /// 
        public PartialViewResult OutageSearch()
        {
            long totalRows;
            long totalPages;
            bool returnStatus;
            string returnErrorMessage;

            OutageBLL OutageBLL = new OutageBLL();

            Models.OutageViewModel outageViewModel = new Models.OutageViewModel();

            this.UpdateModel(outageViewModel);

            List Outages = OutageBLL.OutageSearch(
                outageViewModel,
                outageViewModel.CurrentPageNumber,
                outageViewModel.PageSize,
                outageViewModel.SortBy,
                outageViewModel.SortAscendingDescending, 
                out totalRows,
                out totalPages,
                out returnStatus,
                out returnErrorMessage);

            ViewData["Outages"] = Outages;

            outageViewModel.TotalPages = totalPages;
            outageViewModel.TotalRows = totalRows;

            ViewData.Model = outageViewModel;

            return PartialView("OutageSearchResults");

        }


         /// 
        /// Get Outage Information
        /// 
        /// 
        public JsonResult GetOutageInformation()
        {

            bool returnStatus;
            string returnErrorMessage;
            List returnMessage;

            OutageBLL outageBLL = new OutageBLL();

            Models.OutageViewModel outageViewModel = new Models.OutageViewModel();

            this.TryUpdateModel(outageViewModel);

            Outage outage = outageBLL.GetOutageInformation(
                outageViewModel.OutageID, 
                out returnStatus, 
                out returnErrorMessage,
                out returnMessage);

            outageViewModel.UpdateViewModel(outage, typeof(Outage).GetProperties());

            outageViewModel.ReturnMessage = returnMessage;
            outageViewModel.ReturnStatus = returnStatus;
            outageViewModel.OutageScheduledDate = UtilitiesBLL.FormatDate(outageViewModel.ScheduledDate);
            outageViewModel.OutagePlannedDuration = UtilitiesBLL.FormatDuration(outageViewModel.PlannedDuration);

            return Json(outageViewModel);

        }
```

Comment: Sure...I did not post code in my original question because I am not sure where the problem is. What would be the most helpful...View, partialview or the controller?

Comment: Maybe to code that renders the PartialView and the Controller action

Comment: Are you sure you are using exactly the same assemblies in both cassini and IIS? Both from your project and MVC.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by cassini?

Comment: Just found - default Visual Studio Development Server (aka Cassini). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469555/any-tutorials-about-how-to-create-an-asp-net-mvc-2-website-and-run-it-against-loc

Comment: Not sure about the *assemblies* question. I have published the project to the IIS 7 server and the MVC dll is in my /bin folder. What else do I need to look for?

Answer (score 0):

Check your included JavaScript files on the deployed version. If you are missing some files (MicrosoftMvcAjax.js, jQuery.js), the page could simply be posting instead of using an Ajax post.